# Microstrategy Developer error about licenses and/or privileges

Tags: microstrategy

Hi I'm new to MicroStrategy and I hope someone can help me out. Here's the thing I can access the reports using the Web but not on the MicroStrategy Developer tool, and I'm getting the error: "You do not have the licenses or privileges to use the Document Editor". What should I do, and what seems to be causing the problem? TIA

Comment: Contact MicroStrategy support.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get in touch with your Microstrategy admin in your company to get access.

Right now you have - Web Reporter,Web Analyst or Web professional privilege
You should ask for Developer/desktop designer/ architect privilege depending on what actions you will perform on the Desktop.